# How to test the influence of conditional probabilities in a regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, multilevel-analysis

I would like to test how people weight different levels of probabilities.

Assume that there is an action $A$ which might lead to a consequence $C$ with value $W(C)$ with a probability of $p_C$. A judgment $J$ can be made about $A$. To the person it is unclear, whether the consequence of the action is relevant for the judgment of the action. If the action were to be based on the consequence, $J(A)$ would be equal to a rationalistic evaluation of $A$ which I call $R(A)$. The probability, that it is correct to judge the action based on its possible consequence, is  $p_U$. In my study, I assess *all* of the mentioned parameters, including $R(A)$.

Theoretically, this leads to these equations:
$$
J(A)=p_U * R(A)\\
R(A)=p_C*W(C)
$$

Now I would like to know, how the different probabilities $p_U$ and $p_C$ are weighted in the judgment $J(A)$. My idea was to do multiple regressions and compare the coefficients of both probabilities.

The regressions would look like this:
$$
\hat{J}(A)=\beta_U * p_U * R(A)\\
\hat{R}(A)=\beta_C * p_C * W(C)
$$

Is there a way to achieve the kind of comparison I am describing here? How could I do so?

Edit: I can easily compare the influence of $p_U$ on $J(A)$ with the influence of $p_C$ on $R(A)$. However, is there a meaningful way to compare the influence of $p_U$ and $p_C$ on $J(A)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification, I think what you might really tried to do is as follows:

Suppose the population relationships are:
$$
J(A)=\beta_U*p_U * R(A)\\
R(A)=\beta_C*p_C*W(C),
$$
where $\beta_U$ and $\beta_C$ are unknown parameters (otherwise, there is no need to run regression).

Plug $R(A)$ into the first equation gives.

$$
J(A)=\beta_U*\beta_C*p_U * p_C*W(C),
$$

from which you can derive:

(i). the effect of $p_C$ on $J(A)$ is
$$
\frac{\partial J(A)}{\partial p_C}=\beta_U*\beta_C*p_U * W(C);
$$

(ii). the effect of
the effect of $p_U$ on $J(A)$ is
$$
\frac{\partial J(A)}{\partial p_U}=\beta_U*\beta_C*p_C * W(C).
$$

Next all you need to do is to get your estimate for $\widehat{\beta}_U,\widehat{\beta}_C$ from the following two regressions:
$$
J(A_i)=\beta_U * p_{Ui} * R(A_i)+e_{1i},\\
R(A_i)=\beta_C * p_{Ci} * W(C_i)+e_{2i},
$$
both of which could be estimated using OLS.

The influence of $p_U$ and $p_C$ on $J(A)$ is then estimated by plug in $\widehat{\beta}_U,\widehat{\beta}_C$ :

(i). the estimated effect of $p_C$ on $J(A)$ is
$$
\widehat{\frac{\partial J(A)}{\partial p_C}}=\widehat{\beta}_U*\widehat{\beta}_C*p_U * W(C);
$$

(ii). the estimated effect of
$p_U$ on $J(A)$ is
$$
\widehat{\frac{\partial J(A)}{\partial p_U}}=\widehat{\beta}_U*\widehat{\beta}_C*p_C* W(C).
$$

Comment: This looks really promising to me! Thank you very much. I have only one question regarding the notification: How exactly do I interpret $\frac{\partial J(A)}{\partial p_U}$? Why is it a fraction and how would I compute the fit to my data using this approach? And what would be the unit of the effect size?

Comment: @MaxJ. Hi, Max, this means the partial derivative of $J(A)$ with respect to $p_{U}$, which simply means the effect of $p_{U}$ on $J(A)$ holding everything else constant. You may want to review multivariate calculus class, or check this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20partial%20derivative,vector%20calculus%20and%20differential%20geometry.  for the meaning of partial derivative.

Comment: @MaxJ.  The formula for calculating $\frac{\partial J(A)}{\partial p_C}$ and $\frac{\partial J(A)}{\partial p_U}$ are given by the RHS of the last two equations respectively. Because you know $W(c),p_U,p_C$, and you also got $\widehat{\beta}_U$ and $\widehat{\beta}_C$ from the aforementioned regressions, so everything in the formula is known.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!